# Batch - If Else statement not working correctly

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

My batchfile outputs both IF and ELSE IF...

The code goes something like this:

```
 @echo off

    set food=0

        if %food%== LSS 1 (
            echo You have no food.
        ) else if %food%== GTR 1 (
            echo You have %food% food!
        )
pause
```

Can anyone help me out?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what you mean by "working properly"

`== lss` is not a valid comparison operator. If you mean less than or equal to, use `LEQ`

equally, `GEQ` for greater than or equal to

```
`==` = `equ` means equal
neq means not equal
lss less
leq less or equal
gtr greater
geq greater or equal
```

Comment: What made you write it in the first place? o.O

Comment: Well, I started with batch coding 2 weeks ago, and I'm not quite sure what I'm doing :P